# get_permalink vs the_permalink

Tags: post-meta

I am filtering the_permalink to return a custom structure

```
 function append_query_string($url) {
$url_endpoint = get_permalink();
$url_endpoint = parse_url( $url_endpoint );
$url_endpoint = $url_endpoint['path']; 
return '#!'. $url_endpoint;
 }
 add_filter('the_permalink', 'append_query_string');
```

the filter above returns

```
 #!/theme-folder/name-of-article
```

I need to remove the leading #! form that url and I had tried using get_permalink but I have found that the filter does not filter get_pemalink. I have checked the codex and I cannot find a filter for get_permalink. Do you know of a way to filter it so that it will match the_permalink? I can't use the_permalink because it outputs the information to the screen and breaks layout. I can't seem to assign it to a variable either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we [look at `get_permalink` in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/link-template.php#L80), we'll see the various filters applied to this function.

For posts, it's `post_link`, for custom post types, it's `post_type_link`, for pages it's `page_link`, and attachments is `attachment_link`.

Comment: I tried post_link and got a bunch of errors. I change the filter above from the_permalink to post_link and got these errors:   fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Comment: You're calling the function you're filtering within the filter, so you enter a never-ending loop. the value is already passed to the function via the `$url` argument, no need to get the permalink within the function.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I think I got it sorted. checking the source was a good idea. I see lots of stuff in there to play with